# A news feed feature on website

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, so i want to add like a basic program where someone can just fill out like a TITLE, FROM, DATE, WHO, MESSAGE, and make that program upload that to a website and make like a news feed? How can do that?

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: @ Ace what have you done so far?

Comment: @ozil I havn't done anything so cause i don't know where to start. Like i want it to be on the homepage so when someone opens the webpage they see the latest news. But i want the news to be controlled by a basic program that uploads the news

Comment: And by "basic program" you mean a separate application, like a .exe file?

Comment: Well anything really it could be a web design or a program.